# Какой ip нужен конфигам веб-серверов: private или public?

Tags: nginx, ip, apache2

Настраиваю веб-сервера, в конфигах необходимо указать:

- для apache2:
  /etc/apache2/conf.d "VirtualHost **your-ip**:81"
- для nginx:
  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf "upstream B {server **your-ip**:81;}"

Comment: ни тот ни другой. указать нужно тот ip, который закреплён за сетевым интерфейсом машины. см. вывод `$ ip a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

задано, собственно, два *вообще никак не связанных между собой* вопроса. это не принято на stackoverflow, но я дам ответ и на второй вопрос.

#### apache virtualhost

вообще там можно указывать ip-адрес (или доменное имя, в него резолвящееся), доступный локальным процессам для прослушивания. посмотреть доступные адреса можно, например, командой `ip a`. пример:

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.9/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

из него видно, что связь с «внешним миром» для данной машины доступна через один ip-адрес — `172.17.0.9`. в такой ситуации можно этот *единственный* адрес и не указывать, а обойтись указанием «слушать все доступные ip-адреса»:

```
<virtualhost *:81>
```

подробнее о директиве *virtualhost* смотрите в [документации](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost).

#### nginx upstream server

в программе *nginx* [директива *upstream* описывает группу серверов](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream). внутри блока *upstream* серверы могут быть указаны [директивой *server*](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server), в которой адрес может быть указан в виде доменного имени или ip-адреса, и необязательного порта, или в виде пути unix-сокета.

в случае указания ip-адреса это должен быть тот адрес, по которому данный сервер доступен с той машины, где работает программа *nginx*, настройку которой вы и производите.

---

**дополнение**

если обе программы, про которые идёт речь в вопросе — *apache* и *nginx* — запускаются на одной машине, то в обоих конфигурационных файлах можно указать [*loopback*-адрес](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) — `localhost` или `127.0.0.1`. этого будет более чем достаточно для связи между данными программами в данной ситуации.

Comment: Спасибо за подробное разъяснение!